# MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction does not appear to be in Windows 10. What replaces it?

Tags: javascript, windows-10

I'm beginning the process of upgrading an app to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. There is a bit of a problem with `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction` in that it no longer exists. Does anyone know of a replacement function for this?

Comment: Looks like we can't use React's `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` either. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi TheTodd, have you found any solution to this ?

Comment: No I haven't found a solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yep, looks like the replacement is to not use it :)

My Windows 8.1 code:

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
            $(document.body).append('<div class="content" id="divContent"></div>');
        });
```

My Windows 10 Universal App Code:

```
$(document.body).append('<div class="content" id="divContent"></div>');
```

I found this from the Google results cache: [Migrating your Windows 8.1 App to a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app for Windows 10](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jitIj_aDxlwJ:https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebAppsDocs/blob/master/en-US/win10/MigrateToUWP.md%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

> In Windows 10 the SafeHTML security model has been removed. When Migrating an app we should remove all references to the SafeHTML APIs, or if too numerous, feature detect them and provide a shim for environments where they don't exist.